# SQL - Как при выводе строк SELECT заменить значение столбцов?

Tags: sql, база-данных

Имеется две таблицы - members и groups

members:

- id: PRIMARY KEY
- user_id: bigint
- group_id: bigint

groups:

- id: PRIMARY KEY
- group_id: bigint

Вопрос, как при вводе `SELECT * FROM members` вывести другое значение одного столбца, ну например я хочу вывести все столбцы, но мне захотелось изменить отображаемое значение в столбцах.

Зачем? - members и groups связаны между собой FOREIGN KEY,members.group_id у меня ссылается на groups.id, как мне вывести все столбцы, но единственный столбец должен иметь другое значение.

Comment: В select перечисляете столбцы, а там где надо заменить, просто меняете. Покажите пример с данными, что есть и как не получается сделать.

Comment: А если столбцов ну теоретически много, должен же быть какой-то грамотнее способ?

Comment: Либо все, либо перечислением. Если таблицы разные, то можно делать так `select a.*, b.*, c.field1, c.field2` где a, b, c - таблицы

Answer (score 2):

Не очень понятно, что нужно, но попробую угадать.

Просто меняем значение столбца. Увеличиваем значение user_id на единицу.

```
select (user_id+1) as user_id from members;
```

Меняем значение столбца в зависимости от четности

```
select if(user_id%2 <> 0, 'Не четное', 'Четное') as user_id from members
```

Answer (score 1):

С помощью оператора CASE:

```sql
SELECT
    FirstName, LastName,
    Salary, DOB,
    CASE Gender
        WHEN 'M' THEN 'Male'
        WHEN 'F' THEN 'Female'
    END
FROM Employees
```